# How to add badge to Jenkins build using Java code?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to add badge to the job build after the job completes. I found the groovy line to achieve this.

manager.addBadge('star-gold.png', 'SNAPSHOT deployed on DEV')

But I want to do it in java, Can anybody help me?

Comment: As Groovy is natively supported by Jenkins and in most parts it extends Java, I don't see any point of limiting yourself to vanilla Java. Write it in Groovy.

Comment: Ok....I have tried doing it in java but the thing is I am not able to see the badge. The text appears but Instead of image icon, there appears empty icon